# Importing to store using Magento dataflow profile

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm importing multiple products to Magento. I have two stores where I want to import products. I have created two stores in System / Manage Stores, but when I use store name in my csv-file in store column, it will return error "Skipping import row, store "mynewstorename" field does not exist.". If I use admin as store name, then products are imported successfully to Magento.

Version: Magento ver. 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself. When you create new store, you enter value code, and you must enter that code value to store column, not store value.

[image]